# Limes of Lebesgue integral

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

So here's my measure theory problem 
Prove, that if $\mu(X) < \infty$, $f_{n}$ and $f$ are non-negative and bounded by common constant L, and $f_{n} \rightarrow f$ by measure, then $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \int f_{n} \;d\mu = \int f\; d\mu$$
I don't think I should solve by like I normally would in analysis, but I might be wrong. And help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you know Dominated Convergence Theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $g_n = f_n - f$ and note that $g_n$ converges to $0$ in measure if $f_n$ converges to $f$ in measure. Furthermore $|g_n|\leq |f_n|+|f| \leq 2L$. Showing that $\int f_n d\mu \rightarrow \int f d\mu$ is equivalent to showing that $\int g_n d\mu \rightarrow 0$.

Now for any $\epsilon > 0$
\begin{align*} |\int g_n d\mu| &\leq  \int | g_n | d\mu \\ &=  \int_{\{|g_n|> \epsilon  \}} |g_n| d\mu + \int_{\{|g_n| \leq \epsilon\}}|g_n|d\mu \\
&\leq 2L \cdot \mu(\{ |g_n|> \epsilon\}) + \epsilon \mu(X),
\end{align*}
where $\mu(\{|g_n| > \epsilon\}) \rightarrow 0$ for $n\rightarrow \infty$ by definition of convergence in measure. Thus we conclude that the right hand side can be made arbitrarily small and thus $|\int g_n d\mu| \rightarrow 0$ as desired.

Comment: Indeed, I didn't pay attention to the convergence in measure. Nice proof (+1)

Comment: I don't really understand the last step, could you elaborate?

Comment: Acctually, I'm quite surprise by this proof, because it provides a proof of the bounded convergence theorem avoiding Egorov theorem, and thus, make the argument much easier. That's very efficient :-)

Comment: @WPHakoon: Which step ? The fact that $\mu\{|g_n|>\varepsilon \}\to 0$ ? If yes, it comes from the fat that $g_n\to 0$ in measure.

Comment: No, the step that changes the integral on the right, the $\int_{\{|g_{n}|\leq\epsilon\}}|g_{n}| d\mu$

Comment: We have $1_{\{|g_n| \leq \epsilon\}}(x) g_n(x) \leq \epsilon$ for all $x\in X$, so
$$\int_{\{|g_n| \leq \epsilon\}} | g_n| d\mu \leq \int_X \epsilon \: d\mu = \epsilon \cdot \mu(X).$$
Note that this is essentially the step where we need the assumption $\mu(X) < \infty$.

Comment: @Surb The proof is partially inspired by a proof of the fact, that a sequence of random variables is convergent in $L^1$ if and only if it converges in probability and is uniformly integrable. See for instance the proof of Theorem 1 on page 4 in these course notes https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-436j-fundamentals-of-probability-fall-2018/lecture-notes/MIT6_436JF18_lec19.pdf